# webdriver C# - click this element with XPath position?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have an element whit this XPath Position:

```
//td[4]/a
```

I try this but does not work:

```
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@position='//td[4]/a']")).Click();
```

Using C# Webdriver and not java, please.

Comment: I don't want to use by ID because it's a differrent ID for each button, but all of them has the word "Borrar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using:

```
river.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[4]/a")).Click();
```

?
And if you have similiar Problems. You can use the Console in the developer tools of Chrome and write like this:

```
$x("YOUR XPATH HERE")
```

This will result in your element. If that's not the case, then your Xpath is wrong.

Edit: If you want to know the XPath of an element. Go to Developers Tools -> Elements-> Click on your element with the magnifier -> Right Click the Html code ->Click on "Copy Xpath"
For FireFox use: [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firepath/https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firepath/)

Comment: Thanks! And how to click dthe same but second element, I must add [2] where?

Comment: This for the 2 button don't works             driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[4]/a[2]")).Click();

Comment: @Lion6 I don't know how your page looks, so please use my edit for extracting the XPath.

Comment: Thanks you LzyPanda for the trick, but when all the element have the exact xpath, how to click the second element and not repeting every time clickyng the first element?

Comment: It shouldn't have the same xPath. But try (//td[4]/a)[2].

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[4]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question on how to click on second button if it has the same XPath you can do this.

```
var buttons = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[4]/a"));
buttons[0].Click();
buttons[1].Click();
```

Note the plural FindElements.